# How to embed a command into bash which act as built-in?

Tags: c, bash

I have created a command line utility using C programming language. Now I want to embed that command into bash. It should act as bash built-in command 'cd'.
How can I do that??

In the bash source I saw there is a directory called `builtins`. I looked that directory and found there is `*.def` files and there is a file called `cd.def`.

I think this is the definition of bash built-in `cd`. Now my question is how to create my own definition???

Comment: You can't embed it into bash, but you can copy it to someplace in your path, like /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin.  Then to run it all you need to do is type its name.

Comment: You'd have to build a custom version of bash

Comment: You can load new builtins via the `enable` command. This will probably involve modifying the utility so that it is in the correct form to load, though. The source distribution provides many [examples](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/examples/loadables?id=bash-4.3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wish to make your binary a built-in in bash

**Method 1 : bash function**

You can emulate the behavior by creating a bash function in, say `~/.bashrc`, file:

```
function mycommand 
{
/path/to/your/binary #plus arguments if any
}

export -f mycommand
```

and the use `mycommand` just like you use `cd`.

Do have a look at this [[ tldp article ]](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html) on how this differ from an actual built-in.

**Method 2 : using enable**

I thought I would demonstrate this by creating a new builtin for finding factorial. Below is the code I've written :

```
/* Programme to compute the factorial of numbers up to 60 */

#include <bash/config.h>

#if defined(HAVE_UNISTD_H)
  #include <unistd.h>
#endif

#include <bash/shell.h>    // for shell internals
#include <bash/builtins.h> // for struct builtin

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // for atoi

/* For unsigned long long numbers, my system could handle numbers
 * upto 65 when it comes to factorial, but I'm restricting the value
 * to 60 for the sake of the example so naming my builtin 'factorial60' 
 * the wrapper is factorial_wrapper and the actual task of computing the  
 * factorial is done by the function 'factorial'which resides inside the 
 * wrapper.
 */

unsigned long long factorial(unsigned long long x, unsigned long long amt)
{
  if (x == 0)
    return amt;
  else
    amt*=x;
  return factorial(x-1, amt);
}

int factorial_wrapper(WORD_LIST* list) //Wrapper function
{
  char* ptr=NULL;
  int num;
  if (list == 0) {
    builtin_usage();
    fflush(stdout);
    return (EX_USAGE);
  }
  else{
    ptr=list->word->word;

    /* We're expecting one & only one argument here.
     * I haven't checked for multiple arguments for the sake of brevity
     */
    num=atoi(ptr);

    /* atoi is not the best here because it returns zero for invalid conversions
     * I used it just for the sake of this example.
     */

    if (num>60){
    builtin_usage();
    fflush(stdout);
    return (EX_USAGE);
    }

    printf("%llu\n",factorial(num,1));
    fflush(stdout);
  }
  return (EXECUTION_SUCCESS);     // returning 0
}


char *factorial60_doc[] = {
  "factorial60",
  "Usage : factorial60 number",
  "Description :",
  "Gives the factorial of numbers upto 60",
  (char *)NULL
};
//  Make sure the above documentation is sensible
//   You need to supply factorial60_doc to the structure below.


struct builtin factorial60_struct = {
  "factorial60", // builtin name
  factorial_wrapper, // wrapper function for implementing the builtin
  BUILTIN_ENABLED, // initial flags for builtin  - See Reference 1
  factorial60_doc, // array of long documentation strings.
  "Usage : factorial60 'number_upto_60'", // usage synopsis; becomes short_doc
  NULL // reserved for internal use, this a char*
};
```

Compile the code like below :

```
gcc -shared -fpic -o factorial.so factorial.c
```

Copy the shared object factorial.so to to a local lib location say `/usr/local/lib/mylib/`

Enable(persistent) the new builtin  by adding the below in ~/.bashrc (or /etc/bash.bashrc if you wish the new builtin to be used by other users)

```
enable -f /usr/local/lib/mylib/factorial.so factorial60  # You need to give the full path
```

And voila! you have the new builtin ready for use in a new shell session.

```
$ factorial60 24
10611558092380307456
$ factorial60
factorial60: usage: Usage : factorial60 'number_upto_60'
$ type -a factorial60
factorial60 is a shell builtin
$ factorial60 61
factorial60: usage: Usage : factorial60 'number_upto_60'
```

(thanks @chepner for reminding this)

**Method 3 : recompile bash**

Just recompile bash(the dirty way!) with added functionality - [[ source code here ]](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/).

---

**References:**

1. `enable` manpage [[ here ]](http://ss64.com/bash/enable.html).
2. WORD_LIST : Built-in functions are always given a pointer to a list of type WORD_LIST. If the built-in doesn't actually take any options, you must call no_options(list) and check its return value before any further processing. If the return value is non-zero, your function should immediately return with the value EX_USAGE. Check [[ this ]](http://helios.cs.ifmo.ru/~ad/Documentation/Bash_Shell/bash3-APP-C.html).
3. You need to install `bash-builtins` library (I'm on Ubuntu 12.04,The actual package name may differ by distro) to compile new builtins.
4. Check how `builtin_usage` is [[ defined ]](http://www.nanobit.net/doxy-gen/bash-doxy/d7/dce/a00143_a511faeac050ed40f69935dcf7a2b68aa.html#a511faeac050ed40f69935dcf7a2b68aa).
5. To use the enable command, your system should support dynamic loading.
6. In `enable` the name of the builtin (here factorial60) should match the name given in the structure (notice `factorial60_struct`) and `_struct` should be appended to the *builtin name* in the structure.

---

Comment: `cd` is not a binary. If it was it would not change the working directory of the its child process

Comment: You could use a bash function

Comment: @EdHeal : Updated :-)

Comment: `cd` is built in not for performance reasons.

Answer (score -2):

You can also use `alias`, just adding the below line in `~/.bashrc` will do the job.

```
alias commandname='/path/to/your/binary'
```

Answer (score -3):

You could install it into a directly that part of your users path. Usually one of the following:

`"/bin" or "/usr/bin"` - you'll need root access on the machine to do this.

or

`"~/bin"` - if it just for your user and you don't have root access.