# How to tell if a shell command is written in Bash or C?

Tags: c, bash, macos, shell, terminal

I'm using macOS and I noticed (via a separate article) that the [`cat`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/text_cmds/text_cmds-87/cat/cat.c) command is written in C. But I'm sure I've read elsewhere that some shell commands (builtins?) are written in Bash.

How can you tell the difference?

**UPDATE**: seems I was misinformed and that no builtin commands are written in bash. What I must have read was something related to an external executable.

Comment: Read the Bash documentation to see which commands are built into the shell? By the way, why do you want to know?

Comment: bash is written in c btw

Comment: To start with, as you might know, `bash` is a command line interpreter which is written in `C`. The built ins are written in `C` following certain guidelines. You may be confused **between** `shell-scripts` which is (usually) a collection of utilities written in `C` **and** built-ins.

Comment: To find out whether it is a bash script, you can print out the contents of the executable. Find out its path with `which <command>` and then do `cat <path>`. If it's a bash script, you'll see it, if not, it's probably a binary. You'll have to do some further digging to find out what programming language that binary was written in.

Comment: @TheBaj If I am not mistaken, the shell utilities are always written in `C`.

Comment: Right, I think so too. But just in case you'd want to find out what other executables are written in, this could be a starting off point.

Comment: Refer to method2 of [\[ this \]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37361990/1620779) answer for an example of a bash-builtin. As a side-note, built-ins are unarguably faster than their shell-script counterparts

Comment: @TheBaj would make more sense to use `file <path>` as that just gives the file type rather than a screen of mess

Comment: `man file` ......

Comment: @ChrisTurner, that seems like a better solution

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'file' command to determine the type of file.

Built-ins are not written in bash.  The are intrinsically part of the command interpreter (which is often bash).  Example: 'cd'.  The 'file' command will not be able to find a built-in and will give an error.

Answer (score 1):

the difference between a bash builtin and an executable is that when calling from a bash process a builtin is a function call whereas an external command forks a new process (if not in background waits for termination).

note the overhead of calling a new process

```
for((i=0;i<1000;i++)); do /bin/echo -n ; done
```

to know if a command is a builtin or an executable you can use `type`

```
type cat
type -a echo
```

to explicitly call `echo` builtin

```
builtin echo
```

to explicitly call `echo` command

```
command echo
```

note commands that changes process environment like `cd` can't be an executable because calling a sub process can't change caller's environment.